# Display HTML on top of Canvas

Tags: createjs, easeljs

I'm new to EaselJS and in my application I have the main view.
upon clicking a button I would like to open a new view and put an HTML table with some css style sheet.

How can I do this?

I read a little but about the new DOMElement, but understood that it's experimental and buggy.

What a good solid options available?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOMElement is not experimental or buggy, it is just limited. It helps maintain position and transformation of HTML content, as if it is a child of the Stage. Since the element can also be positioned and transformed by HTML and CSS rules outside of EaselJS's control, it may behave unexpectedly. But it is still the recommended approach for HTML content that is controlled by EaselJS.

If you have any specific issues or questions, feel free to ask them here, or post issues to the [EaselJS GitHub issue list](http://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues).

Comment: Does it support css3?

Comment: Where can I see a nice example how to use it?

Comment: There are multiple examples in the EaselJS GitHub. The documentation probably hasn't been updated in some time -- but not much has changed in DOMElement over the years. It uses the CSS3 Matrix for transformation.